# C# String Interpolation Variable Alignment

Tags: c#, text-alignment, string-interpolation

In C#7, (.NET Framework 4.7+), what is the proper way to include a variable in the alignment component for string interpolation?

The following code gives an error *"constant value is expected"* for the alignment component.

```
var x = 5;
var test = $"{"blue",x}";
```

The [C# specs for string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) alignment element read:

```
{<interpolatedExpression>[,<alignment>][:<formatString>]}
```

> alignment
>
> The constant expression whose value defines the minimum number of
>   characters in the string representation of the result of the
>   interpolated expression....

Is there a workaround for the "constant expression" limitation of the alignment setting? Could this be performed with other built-in functions?

Also curious as to why it was implemented with this limitation.

Comment: If you want the alignment to be defined at runtime, you can use `string.Format`

Comment: @vc74 Looking at [string composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) it seems string.Format is the alternative, though it's not as clean as $ string interpolation. Was hoping there was a workaround of sorts.

Comment: Keep in mind that `FormattableString` instances are transformed at compile time so the compiler needs to know the actual value of the alignment.

Comment: Interpolated strings aren't magic. They are just syntactic sugar for calling `string.Format()`. They simply allow you to reorganize the string so that instead of explicitly providing argument indexes, and then a list of arguments, the compiler does that for you. The usual limitations with `string.Format()` still apply, including the requirement that alignment values be integer literals in the format string. But, you can generate the format string at run-time as a work-around. See marked duplicate for details.

Comment: And don't forget: you can use interpolated strings to create the string format! E.g.: `string test = string.Format($"{{0,{x}}}", "blue");` String interpolation happens at compile-time, so you're stuck calling `string.Format()` explicitly, but interpolation at least lets you create the format string a bit more conveniently.